# Batch files: How to read a file?

Tags: file, batch-file

How you can read a file (text or binary) from a batch file? There is a way to read it in a binary mode or text mode?

Comment: @RookieTEC9: yes, I know that they are 2 completetly different things, but I needed an answer that worked in msdos, not windows nt (or newer versions), also this question was asked 7 years ago, have that in mind

Comment: @RookieTEC9: I think you're right, it's been a while since this. I'll just remove the ms-dos tag

Comment: You can use the command `TYPE [fileName]` for MS-Dos.

Comment: try this out it worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31919715/4534414

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the for command:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (myfile.txt) do @echo %i %j %k
```

Type

```
for /?
```

at the command prompt. Also, you can [parse ini files](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/getini.txt)!

Comment: This is a pretty complex example, parsing very specific information from a particularly formatted text file, without giving any explanation. As per `for /?` the command *would parse each line in myfile.txt, ignoring lines that begin with a semicolon, passing the 2nd and 3rd token from each line to the for body, with tokens delimited by commas and/or spaces.*

Comment: Your example is from cmd.exe's help. You should add a hint for that or copy the whole description.

Answer (score 87):

Under NT-style cmd.exe, you can loop through the lines of a text file with

```
FOR /F %%i IN (file.txt) DO @echo %%i
```

Type "help for" on the command prompt for more information. (don't know if that works in whatever "DOS" you are using)

Comment: This command would quit reading a line if it found a whitespace character. I eventually ended up using FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (file.txt) DO @ECHO %%i

Comment: It works! and If you are using console try %i if you are using a bat file then try %%i .

Answer (score 46):

The FOR-LOOP generally works, but there are some issues.
The FOR doesn't accept empty lines and lines with more than ~8190 are problematic.
The expansion works only reliable, if the delayed expansion is disabled.

Detection of CR/LF versus single LF seems also a little bit complicated.
Also NUL characters are problematic, as a FOR-Loop immediatly cancels the reading.

*Direct* binary reading seems therefore nearly impossible.

The problem with empty lines can be solved with a trick. Prefix each line with a line number, using the findstr command, and after reading, remove the prefix.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ t.txt"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    echo(!var!
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

**Toggling between enable and disabled delayed expansion is neccessary** for the safe working with strings, like `!` or `^^^xy!z`.
That's because the line `set "var=%%a"` is only safe with *DisabledDelayedExpansion*, else exclamation marks are removed and the carets are used as (secondary) escape characters and they are removed too.
But using the variable `var` is only safe with *EnabledDelayedExpansion*, as even a `call %%var%%` will fail with content like `"&"&`.

**EDIT: Added set/p variant**
There is a second way of reading a file with `set /p`, the only disadvantages are that it is limited to ~1024 characters per line and it removes control characters at the line end.
But the advantage is, you didn't need the delayed toggling and it's easier to store values in variables

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=%~1"

for /f "delims=" %%n in ('find /c /v "" %file%') do set "len=%%n"
set "len=!len:*: =!"

<%file% (
  for /l %%l in (1 1 !len!) do (
    set "line="
    set /p "line="
    echo(!line!
  )
)
```

**For reading it "binary" into a hex-representation**
You could look at [SO: converting a binary file to HEX representation using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648636/463115)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the use of `set /p`. I used `set /p value=< result.txt` get the first line from a text file

Comment: Jeb, I asked a related question based on your solution above in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408295/with-dos-batch-file-how-to-parse-a-file-and-output-part-to-one-file-part-to-an

Comment: What about the EOF (end-of-file) character, ASCII `0x1A`? does `for /F` behave the same way as with NUL (`0x00`) characters?

Comment: @aschipfl I suppose the 0x1A behaves in some cases like a linefeed (or better it is translated to a linefeed). [Is there a way to create a SUB without using a temp file ?](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2863&start=15)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it's foolproof even if the lines start with `:` or `;` or contain `!`

Answer (score 17):

One very easy way to do it is use the following command:

```
set /p mytextfile=< %pathtotextfile%\textfile.txt
echo %mytextfile%
```

This will only display the first line of text in a text file. The other way you can do it is use the following command:

```
type %pathtotextfile%\textfile.txt
```

This will put all the data in the text file on the screen. Hope this helps!

Comment: Very big danger here: Limit on such a line is 1023 characters. So set /p reads ONLY first 1023 characters. Would be cool if you could add this to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**settings.ini**

```
name="John"
lastName="Doe"
```

**script.bat**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (settings.ini) do (
    if %%a==name set %%a=%%b
    if %%a==lastName set %%a=%%b
)

echo %name% %lastName%
```

Comment: That's probably a solution, but not for the asked question

Answer (score 1):

Well theres a lot of different ways but if you only want to DISPLAY the text and not STORE it anywhere then you just use: `findstr /v "randomtextthatnoonewilluse" filename.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq eol= tokens=* delims= " %%a in (`findstr /n ^^^^ "name with spaces.txt"`) do (
    set line=%%a
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    echo(!line!
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Of the main code of the page. Quotes are not positionned correctly, the code is not suited for files with name with spaces. Mine is. I give here the trick of the ^^^^

Comment: You're right with the quotes around the filename, but your code has some issues: `eol=` and `delims=` are superfluous, `set line=%%a` should use quotes and without toggling the delayed expansion mode, the code can't read exclamation marks