# batch script - read line by line

Tags: batch-file

I have a log file which I need to read in, line by line and pipe the line to a next loop.

Firstly I grep the logfile for the "main" word (like "error") in a separate file - to keep it small. Now I need to take the seperate file and read it in line by line - each line needs to go to another loop (in these loop I grep the logs and divide it in blocks) but I stuck here.

The log looks like

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - "http://www.blub.com/something/id=?searchword-yes-no" 200 - "something_else"
```

with a for /f loop I just get the IP instead of the complete line.

How can I pipe/write/buffer the whole line? (doesn't matter what is written per line)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOS batch files: How to read a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206114/dos-batch-files-how-to-read-a-file)

Answer (score 73):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  echo line=%%a
)
pause
```

because of the `tokens=*` everything is captured into `%a`

**edit**:
to reply to your comment, you would have to do that this way:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do call :processline %%a

pause
goto :eof

:processline
echo line=%*

goto :eof

:eof
```

Because of the spaces, you can't use `%1`, because that would only contain the part until the first space. And because the line contains quotes, you can also not use `:processline "%%a"` in combination with `%~1`. So you need to use `%*` which gets `%1 %2 %3 ...`, so the whole line.

Comment: thx - works perfect. could you explain why following statement did not work 

for /F %%f in (searchpattern.txt) do (call :PROCESS4 %%f 
)
GOTO END4
:PROCESS4
set var4=%1

goto end4
:end4

its basicly the same. i understand that without a definde "tokens" it will take the whole line 
put it in the var4 and i could work with it. but why it do not work 

please bring light in the darkness 
thank you

Comment: @user553499, I edited my answer explaining how to do this in combination with call.

Answer (score 7):

The "call" solution has some problems.

It fails with many different contents, as the parameters of a `CALL` are parsed twice by the parser.
These lines will produce more or less strange problems

```
one
two%222
three & 333
four=444
five"555"555"
six"&666
seven!777^!
the next line is empty

the end
```

Therefore you shouldn't use the value of `%%a` with a call, better move it to a variable and then call a function with only the name of the variable.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ t.txt"`) do (
    set "myVar=%%a"
    call :processLine myVar
)
goto :eof

:processLine
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!%1!"
set "line=!line:*:=!"
echo(!line!
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 5):

This has worked for me in the past and it will even expand environment variables in the file if it can.

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (LogName.txt) do (
     echo %%a>>MyDestination.txt
)
```

Comment: I wasn't asking a question, I was answering it.  So I guess the answer was not clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

For those with spaces in the path, you are going to want something like this:
n.b. It expands out to an absolute path, rather than relative, so if your running directory path has spaces in, these count too.

```
set SOURCE=path\with spaces\to\my.log
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%SOURCE%") DO (
    ECHO %%A
)
```

To explain:

```
(path\with spaces\to\my.log)
```

Will not parse, because spaces.
If it becomes:

```
("path\with spaces\to\my.log")
```

It will be handled as a string rather than a file path.

```
"usebackq delims="
```

[See docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) will allow the path to be used as a path (thanks to Stephan).

Comment: that's why the switch `usebackq` exists. `More` is a bad choice for big files, as it will wait for a keypress every 64k (if I remember correctly) in batch-mode and replaces TABs with SPACEs. `Type` would be a better choice. Best solution: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("file with spaces.txt") do ...'

Comment: Thanks Stephan! Was at the end of a long day trying to figure out what went wrong with a colleague's script, and found they'd copy-pasta'd the code from here, so wanted to float this so others don't do the same thing! 'Type' is indeed what I wanted. As a note - 'more' works on a page-by-page basis, without a page to limit it to, my undertanding is it will just keep going (just ran it over a 2MB log).

Comment: "Without a page limit" is not quite right. I admit 65536 lines is a far stretched limit, but [it *is* a limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833867/how-to-delete-lines-1-and-3-to-19-in-a-csv-file) (and a log file might easily overcome that)

Comment: Ahh, I read that as 64k bytes (thus mentioning a file size). And yes, a log certainly would. Further - more seems to be incredibly slow with long files (presumably because this was never its intended use).