# Store file output into variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to store the output of text file into a variable, so I can pass the whole file as parameter.

I am using Windows 2003 Server.

The text files have multiple lines like:

```
10.20.210.100 fish
10.20.210.101 rock
```

I was using:

```
Set /P var=<file.txt
```

It reads only the first line of the file.

I tried with `FOR` loop also but it assigned only the last line to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to get the complete content of a file into one variable.
A variable has a limit of ~8100 length.
And it is complicated to get CR/LF into a variable

But with a FOR-loop you can get each single line.

Try a look at [batch script read line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527877/batch-script-read-line-by-line/4531177#4531177)

**EDIT:**
To get each line in a single variable you can use this

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /f "delims=" %%a IN (example.txt) do (
  set /a n+=1
  set "line[!n!]=%%a"
  echo line[!n!] is '%%a'
)
set line
```

or to get all in only one variable (without CR/LF)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line="
for /f "delims=" %%a IN (example.txt) do (
  set "line=!line! %%a"
)
echo !line!
```

Comment: Same thing can be achieve in much simple way. But it not solve my problem.

Comment: But what is your concrete problem? If you can read the file, line by line you could examine each line.

Comment: My object is to assign either all lines to single variable or each line per variable.

Comment: Thanx  jeb. But if you echo %line% it contains each line no of line in file times. And if you use echo! Line! ,it contain one !line! also with other line.  I did a little modification in script and now I am getting expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Jeb’s script is working perfect,  But if you echo %line% it contains each line no of line in file times. And if you use echo !Line! ,it contain one !line! also with other line.  I did a little modification in script and now I am getting expected result.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line="
for /f "delims=" %%a IN (example.txt) do (
set "line1=%%a"
set "line=!line1! and  %%a"
)
echo !line!
```

or

```
echo %line%
```

Now you will get same result in bot cases.