# How to save some text from a file to a variable in cmd?

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I have a `.txt` file containing `D: random text` and I want to select from the `.txt` file only the first `2` letters as the content of a  variable (in CMD):

```
echo D: random text > C:\Users\%USERNAME%\textfile.txt
```

Expected:

```
echo %variable%
"D:"
```

Comment: `for /f %a in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\textfile.txt) do set "var=%a"`. See `for /?` for details.

Comment: @Stephan's command will get you the 1st space/tab separated word from the last line of the file. To be more precise to your demand use `set /p "variable="<"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\textfile.txt"` and `set "variable=%variable:~0,2%"`

Comment: @LotPings: yes. The file has only one line (see how it's generated) and the first two characters are followed by a space. Yours is more generic, but takes the first two letters of the first line of the file (doesn't matter, if LastLine = FirstLine). As the question stands, both approaches are valid.

Comment: I'd do this: `< "%UserProfile%\textfile.txt" set /P Variable=""`, then `echo(%Variable:~,2%`...

Comment: Related: [Store file output into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4584189)...

Comment: Thanks all to answers. All solutions were successfuls