# How to delete the first line of a file using Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-files, findstr

How to delete the first line of a file using Batch?

I really need help... I've tried everything but it didn't work. :(
I've tried this :

```
@echo off
Type test.txt | findstr /I /V /C:"So, lets remove this line" >>Test2.txt
exit
```

Comment: the question is in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tasks are clumsy with pure batch techniques (and mangles characters) - this is a robust solution and uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` that uses built in jscript-ing from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file.

```
type "file.txt"|findrepl /v /o:1:1 >"newfile.txt"
```

Another method is to use `more.exe` but it has limitations with the number of lines at 64K and it mangles TAB characters.

```
more +2 <file.txt >newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=" %A in (c:\windows\win.ini) do echo %A
echo on)
```

Comment: As written, this will strip blank lines and lines that begin with `;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through your file line by line and output each line, except the first one.

From your example it looks like you might be looking for a specific string.

try this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527877/batch-script-read-line-by-line) .. it might help you get you on your way.

Comment: How to output all lines except 1st one?

Answer (score 0):

To delete 1st line of text file:

```
more +1 testfile
```

or

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %i in ('type "testfile" ^| find /v /n ""') do (
REM ove prefixed line numbers:
set a=%i
set a=!a:*]=! 
echo:!a!)
```

Tested in Win 10 cmd.