# How to move folders with names listed in a text file

Tags: windows, directory, move

I face the following issue in Windows. I have thousands of subfolders in a main folder (let's call it data\ ) and I want to move a big subset of them in another folder (let's call it data2\ ). In a .txt file I have a list of the exact names of the folders that I want to move. 
Is there a way to do that with the cmd?

I make a simple example to make the issue more clear. In the folder data\ I have the subfolders A, B, C, D and E. In a text file I have the list of names:

A C E (one name in each line)

I want to move the subfolders A, C and E to the folder data2.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Which programming language? Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: You are asking to do this with cmd on windows, so I assume you mean DOS. You can check this to read file in dos http://stackoverflow.com/a/4527915/3885927 and then use move command instead of echo that was shown in the link

Comment: Yes, I meant DOS... Sorry if I was not clear enough and thanks for the link you provided me and for your suggestions. I've been searching a lot in google...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using PowerShell instead of plain cmd.  You can take advantage of various Linux command aliases.  To move the folder `data\A` to `data2\A` it is as easy as `mv data\A data2`.  Now you also need to do this as part of a loop, because you have a text file containing the names of all these folders that you would like to move.  I am not on a windows system right now, so I can't test the below code.  I adapted a for loop that I saw [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730958.aspx)

```
$files = cat list.txt
foreach ($f in $files)
    { mv data\$f data2 }
```