# How to persistently add directories to PATH when using SETLOCAL?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make an environment variable survive ENDLOCAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262287/make-an-environment-variable-survive-endlocal)
>   [How to keep the value of a variable outside a  Windows batch script which uses “delayed expansion local” mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020152/how-to-keep-the-value-of-a-variable-outside-a-windows-batch-script-which-uses)

I have a batch file that goes something like this:

```
REM I need to use SETLOCAL so as not to pollute the environment
REM with any variables used to implement the logic in this script
SETLOCAL
SET I_DONT_WANT_THIS_VARIABLE_TO_LEAK_OUTSIDE=c:\

REM BUT, there is this one change to the environment I want to make sticky:
PATH %PATH%;%I_DONT_WANT_THIS_VARIABLE_TO_LEAK_OUTSIDE%
```

The script uses `SETLOCAL` to isolate the environment from whatever the batch file wants to do, but this causes a problem: at the end I *do* want to modify the caller's environment in some very specific manner, but `SETLOCAL` prevents this (the change is undone as soon as the batch file exits). I also cannot call `ENDLOCAL` before setting the path because that restores the environment to its original state, wiping out the value of the variable so I cannot append its value to the path.

**Is there a way to set the path while ignoring the `SETLOCAL` in effect? Alternatively, is there any trick to explicitly preserve the value of a variable from being wiped out when calling `ENDLOCAL`?**

I am aware that it's possible to use a temp file as a vessel that can bypass the `ENDLOCAL` barrier, but a more elegant solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to the end of your script (or just before you return):

```
endlocal & @set path=%path%
```

The reason that this works is that the cmd parser performs environment variable expansion to the entire line before executing any of it.  So by the time `endlocal` executes, the line that `cmd` is processing looks like:

```
endlocal & @set path=c:\whatever\the;c:\new\path;c:\is
```

Then `endlocal` throws away all the local changes, but the ones made to the path have been temporarily preserved in the `set` command that's about to be executed.

Comment: The `@` is optional, of course. If multiple variables need to be saved, `endlocal & (<br>set var1=%var1%<br>set var2=%var2%<br>...<br>)` may be slightly more convenient.

Comment: Like the egg of Columbus: obvious in retrospect. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon: almost nothing in cmd scripting is obvious beyond executing a simple list of commands.