# Date Parsing in Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-scripting

I am having problems with the following batch file.  On first run it doesn't output the date properly in the file.  On first run i get the following:

```
*Start of batch file ~4,2dt:~6,2dt:~2,2dt:~8,2dt:~10,2* 
*End of batch file ~4,2dt:~6,2dt:~2,2dt:~8,2dt:~10,2*
```

on next run it works properly:

```
*Start of batch file 10/18/13 06:46*
*End of batch file 10/18/13 06:46*
```

One thing to note is that the log file didn't exist on the first run so it could be related to that?!?!?

Here is my Batch File:

```
set logFile=C:\log.txt
echo %logFile%

REM Get the Start Date and Time and Parse it out
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a 
set start=%dt:~4,2%/%dt:~6,2%/%dt:~2,2% %dt:~8,2%:%dt:~10,2%

ECHO Start of batch file %start% >>%logFile%
REM Run some procedure

REM Get the End Date and Time and Parse it out
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a 
set end=%dt:~4,2%/%dt:~6,2%/%dt:~2,2% %dt:~8,2%:%dt:~10,2%

ECHO End of batch file %end% >>%logFile%
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of your For statement are expanded before executing and therefore dt is empty at first.

Add "setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" to the top of your batch file.
Also replace % with ! for all your expansions of dt.
So the set start and end strings become "!dt:~4,2!/!dt:~6,2!/!dt:~2,2! !dt:~8,2!:!dt:~10,2!"

See the "set" help by running "set /?"

See [How do SETLOCAL and ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-usage-question)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Can you clarify what you mean by: "Also replace % with ! for all your expansions of dt"

Comment: So the set start and end strings become "!dt:~4,2!/!dt:~6,2!/!dt:~2,2! !dt:~8,2!:!dt:~10,2!"