# Reading values in a text file and subsequent processing

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

A text file contains values. These values are to be used as an argument to an executable.
I tried the following to see how I can use inputs (line by line) from a file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (test.txt) do (
set n1=%%i
echo %n1%
echo "done"
)
```

test.txt contains numbers: Ex.

```
0.1
0.002
3
20
```

The output of the set of batch commands processed from a batch file is:

```
20
"done"
20
"done"
20
"done"
20
"done"
```

What went wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access variables inside a code block you need `delayed expansion`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in (test.txt) do (
    set "n1=%%~i"
    echo !n1!
    echo "done"
)
```

Please note: delayed expanded variables need exclams instead of percents.

---

In this part of code you do not need `delayed expansion` if you use the for loop parameter `%%i` as "variable":

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in (test.txt) do (
    echo %%i
    echo "done"
)
```

But you cannot make string conversion  like `set "n1=!n1:.0=.!"` with `%%i`.

Comment: sounds about right... here's some discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-usage-question

Comment: That works. I understand that !n1! is to obtain the modified value for every iteration. Why the ~ ?
Additionally, It tried to perform a multiplication-
set /a n2=!n1!*10
echo !n2!
.The result was that I got 0 for 0.1 and 0.002 along with a 'Missing operator'. The result for the other two values was good (30 and 200)

Comment: `cmd` doesn't know decimal numbers. You can use only integers.

Comment: `%%~` the tilde is usual writing in Batch programmers to remove possibly occurring double quotes. It's not necessary here, but also not harmful.

Comment: without the multiplication I see decimals in the cmd. i will modify my text file accordingly (0.02 instead of 0.002). And would you say I can use !n1! as an input parameter for an executable ?

Comment: Yes you can pass `!n1!` as parameter. To remove one zero use this code: `set "n1=!n1:.0=.!"`