# Batch how to check specific files modified date in folder

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvrec.b*" "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvrec.d*" "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvrec.lg*" "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvpdt.a*"') do (
    set fileDateTime=%%~tf
    set fileName=%%f
    echo %fileDateTime%
    echo %fileName%
)
```

As the code above, I want to list down the modified date of the files in the folder, however, it doesn`t work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in the beginning of the script, and use `!variable!` instead of `%variable%`.

For the detail of `EnableDelayedExpansion`, please refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464353/2749114.

You also need to add option `/s` to `dir` to get the full path of your file to get the data time correctly. And then if you only want the file name, use `%%~nxf` instead of `%%~f`.

Here are the codes.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /s "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvrec.b*" "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvrec.d*" "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvrec.lg*" "\\rspdb1\e$\master10\rspadvpdt.a*"') do (
    set fileDateTime=%%~tf
    set fileName=%%~nxf
    echo !fileDateTime!
    echo !fileName!
)
```

Comment: I`m sorry that I forgot to mention "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" is already at the start of code, and !fileDateTime! did not work.

Comment: Just modified the answer. To get the data time, you need to pass "/s" to "dir" to get the full path of your file. And then use "%%~nxf" to get the file name from the full path.

Comment: Excellent. It works. Thanks a lot for the valuable time and answer

Comment: Hi, I want to put a if else statement in the for loop as well , like if !fileDateTime:~0,10! == 01/09/2014, however it does not work, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add quotes, like `if "!fileDateTime:~0,10!" == "01/09/2014"`.