# Why is setting a batch script variable delayed?

Tags: batch-file

How do I solve delayed variable assignment?

*(I'm making the term delayed variable assignment up, because it seems like a reasonable descriptive phrase).*

Example Batch Script Code script.bat:

```
@echo off
set mylocation=%CD%
echo mylocation %mylocation%
echo CD %CD%
```

Actual Output

```
C:> script.bat
mylocation
CD C:\

C:>
```

What I want it to do (or thought it would do)

```
C:> script.bat
mylocation C:\
CD C:\

C:>
```

Edit (changed): If I echo %mylocation% in command prompt after the script ends it has a value.

```
C:>echo %mylocation%
C:\

C:>
```

Edit: This is the original Code, and you can view the youtube video https://youtu.be/jQzEFD3yISA - where I try to show as much detail as possible so that, everything is exact.

```
@echo off

set natasha_command=%1

if %natasha_command% == start (
    set mylocation=%CD%
    echo mylocation %mylocation%
    echo CD %CD%
)

goto :eof
```

Comment: Not an answer obviously but your script works on my machine. I get that output that you expected.

Comment: So if it works perfectly fine for you, is there anything else that could cause it, to sparingly not operate occasionally?

Comment: You need to show us exactly the code you are using by cutting and pasting. `olddir` is not mentioned in the snippet you've provided, so it seems you're showing different code from that which you are using. It's important to aste in-context, since for instance a stray space could cause the problem you've described or more likely you're setting and displaying a variable in a conditional-bracket.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18464353/19719) help?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to post the code, and upload a video to youtube to show it. Cheers.

Comment: the description in indiv's link is correct, but maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) is better understandable.

Comment: Cheers indiv, cheers Stephan!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.