# Looping through string values using set in Windows cmd

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, set, delayedvariableexpansion

My Windows batch file is supposed to read file names and create a directory that is named according to the filename's 2nd to 5th letter:

```
for %%f in (.\*.txt) do (
set string=%%~nf
mkdir %string:~2,5%     
)
```

The value of 'string' is not updated though, i.e. it is the same in each step of the loop. How can I have it updated?

This is the cmd output:

```
>for %f in (.\*.txt) do (
set string=%~nf
 mkdir le3
)

>(
set string=file1
 mkdir le3
)

>(
set string=file2
 mkdir le3
)
A subdirectory or file le3 already exists.

>(
set string=file3
 mkdir le3
)
A subdirectory or file le3 already exists.
```

Comment: Try consulting the hundreds of articles on SO about `delayedexpansion`. Essentially, a `%var%` within a code block is replaced by the value of `var` when the block is parsed. To access the changing value within a block, you feed first to invoke `delayedexpansion` using a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command, and then use `!var!` to access the dynamic value of the variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I consulted several sites, e.g. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/how-do-setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-work) and came up with 'SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION for %%f in (.\*.txt) do ( set !string!=%%~nf mkdir !string:~2,5! )' - but the delayed expansion does not seem to work yet. Do you have any advice what's wrong?

Comment: `set !string!=%%~nf` should be `set string=%%~nf` - you intend to set the variable `string`, not the variable `current content of string`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is because of `%variable% expansion`. The entire `FOR` statement (including up to the closing parenthesis) is one statement. When it is read, the command processor replaces the `%string%` variable with whatever *string* is set to *before* the `SET` inside executes. (Actually, you're getting the subset of *string* starting at the 2nd character and proceeding 5 characters, but that's not really important here. My guess is that you've got `%string%` set to "file3".)

Anyway, you can fix it by adding `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top and using syntax like `!string!` instead of `%string%` inside the `FOR`.

You could also move the processing of `%string%` outside of `FOR`.

Look up `HELP SETLOCAL` and `HELP SET` for more.

Also, if you hadn't noticed, you're not getting the second and fifth characters of the filename... As I mentioned, you're getting a substring of (up to) length 5, starting at character 2. Look up `HELP SET` for more.

Comment: I have now enabled delayed expansion and adapted the code:
`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (.\*.txt) do (
set !string!=%%~nf
mkdir !string:~2,5!  
)`
I understand the idea, also tried setting the quotation marks in different places, but still I don't get the delayed expansion to work - Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly, you've got a couple of unnecessary exclamation marks in your last attempt:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set string=%%~nf
    if not exist "!string:~2,5!\" mkdir "!string:~2,5!"
)
```

Comment: I helps the site and prosective responders if you mark correct answers accordingly.