# Batch - turn off EnableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have turned on EnableDelayedExpansion:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

How can I turn it off (using code)?

Comment: It depends on the situation...`setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` or `EndLocal`. But If you use the latter, you'll lose all variables you've changed/created after the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Answer (score 2):

Use `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion`. On the command prompt, type `setlocal /?` to see this indicated. This [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/how-do-setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-work) question (not a dupe) suggests using `setlocal /?` to get help with `setlocal` and also provides more information about `setlocal` in general.