# how to for loop and check if a number of file is present in the folder .bat

Tags: batch-file

I am looping trough a folder. I want to understand if there are 20 zip files. If these 20 zip files are present then another batch will call. Otherwise I need to build a powershell script to send an email to somebody as error message

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 1
for /f %%a in (\\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\SSC_Proj\*.zip) do (
   set /a count += 1
   set "TRUE="
   if %%~xa=.zip && %%~xa == 20  set TRUE = 1
   ECHO "there are 20 files Matrioska Process starts"
   IF defined TRUE (
      C:\Users\RefosLeo\Desktop\Python\motherbatch.bat
      ) ELSE (
         EXIT
   )
)
```

Please tell me what is wrong because, actually this code does not work

Comment: Does replacing `IF defined TRUE (` with `if %%~xa=.zip && %%~xa == 20 (` work? You are assigning a value to variable `%TRUE%`, but doing that inside `(` `)` requires `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/how-do-setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-work )

Comment: It seems it is not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**untested**
You can use `find` to count the number of files and just use the count directly:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b \\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\SSC_Proj\*.zip ^| find /c /v ""') do (
   if /i %%a EQU 20 (
      rem do what you want here when it equals 20
      C:\Users\RefosLeo\Desktop\Python\motherbatch.bat
   )
)
```

This finds *exactly* 20 zip files.  You could change EQU to GEQ if you actually want to find 20 *or more* .zip files.

Though you might want the inverse -- exit when less than or not equal to 20:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b \\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\SSC_Proj\*.zip ^| find /c /v ""') do (
   if /i %%a LSS 20 exit
)
rem continue here with the rest of your script
C:\Users\RefosLeo\Desktop\Python\motherbatch.bat
```

That is anything less than 20.  If you want to exit when not equal (so less than **or** greater than 20) you would use `if /i %%a NEQ 20 exit`

If you want to continue with the method you started with, I think the following might be what you were going for:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 0
for /f %%a in (\\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\SSC_Proj\*.zip) do (
   set /a count += 1
   if /i !count! EQU 20 (
      ECHO "there are 20 files Matrioska Process starts"
      C:\Users\RefosLeo\Desktop\Python\motherbatch.bat
   )
)
if /i %count% LSS 20 exit
```

You can't put the exit inside the for loop because you'll never know until the for loop is complete that you didn't reach 20 zip files.

Comment: Unlike the code in the original question, which attempts to find and count only `.zip` files, this does not. The count will relate to files whose extensions begin with `.zip`. *It may not have been important in this specific case, hence the acceptance, but I thought I'd mention it anyhow.*

Answer (score 0):

There isn't actually any need for a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), delayed expansion, or setting any variables, to perform your task. Here therefore is a method which uses [xcopy](/questions/tagged/xcopy) and [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr).

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" "\\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\SSC_Proj\*.zip" . /LQ^
 | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "\<20\>" 1> NUL && (
    "C:\Users\RefosLeo\Desktop\Python\motherbatch.bat") || (Exit /B)
```

The above has a flaw, in that it counts any files with extensions beginning with `.zip` as opposed to those which are exactly `zip`. If this is an issue to you, you could try using `where.exe` and [find](/questions/tagged/find) instead:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%where.exe" "\\ITWS2162\work\SCM\RawData\SSC_Proj":"*.zip" 2> NUL^
 | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N "" | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" "[20]" 1> NUL && (
    "C:\Users\RefosLeo\Desktop\Python\motherbatch.bat") || (Exit /B)
```

The examples above are both single line commands, split over several lines for readability. I have left the parenthesized command `(Exit /B)` as you had, because you'll likely want to replace `Exit /B` with your command(s) to build and send the email. *You may, depending upon your specific circumstances, wish to `Call` `motherbatch.bat` instead.*