# How to quote the variable which in the same url by "curl -O"

Tags: url, curl

I want to download some file like:

```
http://example.com/host/file001/file001_0001~0100.jpg
http://example.com/host/file002/file002_0001~0100.jpg
http://example.com/host/file003/file003_0001~0100.jpg
...
http://example.com/host/file100/file100_0001~0100.jpg
```

so I try some simple cmd like

```
curl -O http://example.com/host/file[001-100]/file[001-100]_[0001-0100].jpg
```

but I don't want to acess some url like

```
http://example.com/host/file001/file002_0001~0100.jpg
http://example.com/host/file010/file020_0001~0100.jpg
```

./filexxx/filexxx_0001~0100.jpg ...

both xxx are same in url

What command or symbol should I use?
Sorry for basic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batchfile lime this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%f in (1,1,100) do (
    set form=0000%%f
    set value=!form:~-3!
    ECHO curl -O http://example.com/host/file!value!/file!value!_0!value!.jpg
)
```

If you like the output, remove the `ECHO` before curl...

more info :

- [enabledelayedexpansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/how-do-setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-work)
- `!form:~3!` will get the last 3 characters from the variable `form`

BTW: if you are not using Windows, than please say so, i can convert this to bash too