# cmd for loop error 'in was unexpected at this time'

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, directory

I'm writing a cmd file that will loop through all the directories in a given directory and generate swagger code for each file in each directory. I cannot get the correct syntax for the 'for' loops.

```bash
cd C:\Users\Sora Teichman\Documents\APIJsonModels\models
for /D %%A in ("C:\Users\Sora Teichman\Documents\APIJsonModels\models\*") do (
    set fileFolder=%cd%
    echo %fileFolder%
    for /F %%G in (fileFolder) do (
        set filePath=%f
        echo %filePath%
        java -jar .\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i filePath -l csharp-dotnet2 -o fileFolder
    )
)
```

I'm getting `'in was unexpected at this time'` at the outer for loop. I tried using a variable for the folder path, I tried with the asterisk and without, I tried `('dir "C:\Users\Sora Teichman\Documents\APIJsonModels\models"')`.
The [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) does not provide enough detail for my scenario.
What is the correct syntax for this?
I know that I need double %% for the parameters because this is in a .cmd file, there are many question online for this issue :).
For context, I am running this command file from a .csproj file using an `<Exec Command="codeGenerator.cmd"/>` tag.

Edit: @Stephan pointed out that I needed to set my variables correctly, but now I need help with the inner loop. When I use the `fileFolder` variable, the error I get is 'The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Sora.' It is getting stuck on the space in the folder path.

Comment: Please read [about using variables in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: What is `%f` supposed to be?

Comment: @aschipfl %f I need to get the current file path with the name into a variable; I haven't figured that out yet

Comment: @Stephan, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Will add my answer when I figure this out fully.

Comment: That's because of the space, which splits your string into two. Use quotes. As best practice use them with every folder/file name. Your `java` line should probably be `java -jar ".\swagger-codegen-cli.jar" generate -i "!filePath!" -l csharp-dotnet2 -o "!fileFolder!"`

Comment: `%f`: If I read your comment correctly, read the output of `for /?`, especially the "modifiers" section and use `%%~dpG` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own thanks to @Stephan's comment. Here's the working code:

```
set jsonFoldersPath="C:\Users\Sora Teichman\Documents\APIJsonModels\models\*"
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /D %%f in (%jsonFoldersPath%) do (
set fileFolder=%%f
cd !fileFolder!
for %%a in (*) do (
set fileName=%%a
set filePath=!fileFolder!\!fileName!
cd C:\Users\Sora Teichman\Documents\AmazonAPIGenerator
java -jar .\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i "!filePath!" -l csharp-dotnet2 -o "C:\Users\Sora Teichman\Documents\AmazonAPIGenerator\AmazonGeneratedModels" -c "C:\Users\Sora Teichman\Documents\AmazonAPIGenerator\config.json"
)
)
```

You need to enable delayed expansion for variables using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` so that they only evaluate at execution in the loop; read an explanation here: [How do SETLOCAL and ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/how-do-setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-work)

I did not end up using a variable for the `-o` output directory parameters for Swagger because Swagger organizes the code on its own; it generates API, Client and Model namespaces which I customized using a config.json file and the `-c` parameter.
I also plan to replace the hardcoded paths with relative ones.

Comment: No need for variables (as you don't do substring processing) - you can just use `%%f` and  `%%a` directly: `java -jar .\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i "%%f\%%a" -l ...`