# DOS script to read one file into another

Tags: batch-file

I discovered that I couldnt be granted BULKADMIN or SYSADMIN role on my hosted sql server db and trying to bypass the bulk insert operation by creating a .sql file containing insert statements. The insert statements are created using a xls macro, so theres some bit of manual bodyshopping work that I am doing now. So let me draw the problem here.

I have a text file with the following contents -

```
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 1-16332-1008261.psa 
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 1-16332-1011698.psa 
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 1-16332-1023151.psa 
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 1-16332-1035695.psa 
10/07/2011 03:36 PM 1-16332-1023193.psa 
10/07/2011 03:36 PM 1-16332-1035694.psa 
6 File(s) 8,933,754 
2 Dir(s) 1,675,268,096 free
```

What I want to achieve in my final output file is this -

```
insert into xyz.abcd values('10/05/2011', '1-16332-1008261.psa');
insert into xyz.abcd values('10/05/2011', '1-16332-1011698.psa');
insert into xyz.abcd values('10/05/2011', '1-16332-1023151.psa');
insert into xyz.abcd values('10/05/2011', '1-16332-1035695.psa');
insert into xyz.abcd values('10/07/2011', '1-16332-1023193.psa');
insert into xyz.abcd values('10/07/2011', '1-16332-1035694.psa');
go
```

Please take a note that the last two lines from my input text file are to be dinged in my final output sql file. Its kind of automating the xls macro I am manually doing now by dos scripting where the 'insert into xyz.abcd values' is considered to be a constant string which is written to each new line before the actual date and filename from the file been read.
I will name my final output file as a .sql and execute it remotely from my computer.
Can somebody please help me if this can be doable in DOS programming or not.

I have tried to present a similar problem in another post which I am trying to delete, but am unable to do so. Guess I didnt explain the other one properly.

I know I can redirect the string as a literal to a file by the echo command but the challenge is how do I read fraction of a line from one file and put them into a new file.

Thanks!

Comment: You could start with reading [SO DOS batch files: How to read a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206114/dos-batch-files-how-to-read-a-file/4531090#4531090) and `for /?` especially the tokens part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please put following code to notepad and save it as CMD batch file (e.g. Convert2SQLfile.cmd). Then run it from command line with 3 parameters, while:

- 1st parameter contains path to source file from which data will be read
- 2nd parameter contains path to destination file to which data will be saved
- 3rd parameter contains table name which should be stored in SQL command instead of "xyz.abcd" you have in your request

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Standa

```
    @echo off
    SetLocal

    SET App.SourceFile=%1
    SET App.DestinationFile=%2
    SET App.Table=%3


    FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1,4" %%i IN (`type %%App.SourceFile%%`) DO (
        IF #%%j# NEQ ## (
            IF #%%j# NEQ #free# (
                ECHO insert into %App.Table% values ^('%%i', '%%j'^); >> %App.DestinationFile%
            )
        )
    )

    ECHO go >> %App.DestinationFile%
```

Comment: Evianton, Thank you sounds like an understatement!! This works like a charm. This thread may help others who doesnt have BULKADMIN access but want to upload a sql file to the sql server db hosted on a remote server.

Comment: @user982201 What is the purpose of `IF #%%j# NEQ #free#`? I get it, it's part of the original file, see question.