# Batch processing multiple lines to a single line?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, cmd

In batch (.bat) if I have a file that looks like this:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

How can I rewrite the content of that file to be on the same line? e.g:

```
test1, test2, test3
```

Thanks in advance!
Niklas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it!

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%i in (file.txt) do (
set var=%%i
rem The magic below appends the data var with the data var + the var
if defined var set data=!data!, !var!
)
```

Comment: Yes this works, but there are some issues with exclamation marks, carets and empty lines. You can read at [SO:how to read a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206114/dos-batch-files-how-to-read-a-file/4531090#4531090)

Comment: The var variable is not necessary. Also, is better to use "delims=" instead of "tokens=*", that is: `for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do set data=!data!, %%i`, just clear the data variable before the for.

Comment: This is just proof of concept, not the actual code. But yes, I do use enabledelayedexpansion together with the exclamation marks.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `for /f` command to read a file line-by-line. You can then accumulate the results into a variable for final output.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried using the for /f command, but wasn't able to process all lines into one variable. How would you suggest doing it?