# extracting specific lines of data from multiple text files, to convert to a single csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file, command-line-arguments, batch-processing, text-extraction

First, apologies for my poor coding ability, however I have spent a few hours reading the forums and giving it a crack, so I would really appreciate any help with the following problem:

I have 3 text files, from which I would like to take the filename, 3rd line of data, 5th line, and 7th line and pop them into a single CSV, such as follows:

```
filename1, linedata3, linedata5, linedata7
filename2, linedata3, linedata5, linedata7
filename3, linedata3, linedata5, linedata7
```

Simples, eh? not so, for I am rather lacking in my coding "skillz" and could do with your help. Here's what I have so far:

First a batch file (go.bat):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%i in (%1) do >>lines.txt echo %~n1 %%i & goto :EOF
```

Then manual command line entries:

```
go.bat file1.txt
go.bat file2.txt
go.bat file3.txt
```

So, as you can see, I have done this for one line of text, but don't know how to append lines 3 and 5 onto the end of the output. Also, what I'd really like is a proper command line entry so I can do this for all text files in the directory. I tried the following, but seem to be missing something:

```
for %i in (*.*) do go.bat "%i"
```

Any body help?

Thanks muchlies!
James

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist result.csv del result.csv
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set i=0
    for /F "delims=" %%l in (%%f) do (
        set /A i+=1
        set line!i!=%%l
    )
    echo %%f, !line3!, !line5!, !line7! >> result.csv
)
```

This Batch file process all .txt files in the directory, as you said.

Comment: +1, it works, but it fails with exclamation marks and empty lines and it's really hard to solve that

Answer (score 1):

You could read the lines with another construct.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
< %1 (
Set /p line1=

Set /p line2=
Set /p line3=
Set /p line4=
Set /p line5=
Set /p line6=
Set /p line7=
)
Echo %1,!line3!,!line5!,!line7!
```

Or with a loop (Andriy)

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<%1 (
  For /L %%n in (1 1 7) do (
    Set /p line%%n=
  )
)
Echo %1,!line3!,!line5!,!line7!
```

Comment: +1, but I wonder if a `FOR /L` loop would do as well. Something like `< %1 (FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,7) DO SET /P line%%L=)`. Basically, same idea as yours, only it would be a loop instead of repeating similar lines. What do you think?

Comment: @Andriy Your idea (on using a loop to read several lines of the file in several line variables) was already used in the other answer (my answer) in the line `set line!i!=%%l`.

Comment: Yes you can also use a 'for /L' loop, but in my opinion it's a completly different solution than Aacini's

Comment: @Aacini: *jeb* is right, there *is* a difference. The loop I've suggested merely replaces the series of almost identical lines (`SET /P lineX=`). It doesn't change the way the file is being read. This solution reads the file with the `< filename ( … )` construct in conjunction with a set of `SET /P line=` commands (now replaced with a loop), while yours uses a `FOR /F` loop to retrieve the lines. Well, you can now see that for yourself.

Comment: @Andriy: of course, _the method to read the file_ is entirely different: one method use `set /p lineX=` and read just 7 lines, and the other method use `FOR /F` and read all the lines in the file. However, _the method to use a loop to store the lines in several variables_ is practically the same as easily can be seen if we compare the commands that create the variables: `set line!i!=` vs `set /p line%%n=`. In my previous comment I did NOT mention that both answers represent the same solution (as jeb said) nor even the same or similar method...

Comment: ... I just said that your **idea** ON USING A LOOP TO READ SEVERAL LINES IN SEVERAL VARIABLES was previously shown in my answer. That is it. I don't see any reason for your comments. However, after said that, I would like to note that my answer represent the complete solution to the question that James asked, but jeb's answer (and your modification) is just a part of such a solution.

Comment: @Aacini: Yes, it does appear as if I assumed that you were comparing the solutions, not the ways of creating 'arrays' in batch scripting. That was confusing and very wrong of me, I'm sorry. As for my initial question, it was specifically about `SET line%%n=`, which I had a momentary doubt about (and was too lazy to verify it myself). I knew for sure that `SET line!n!=` *was* possible, but `FOR /L` was better suited in that particular situation, and I only wasn't sure whether it could be used there the way I meant it.