# Extract some lines in multiple text files

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have many text files. In those file only few lines interest me. I though that Batch would be efficient to deal with my problem so I spent the last two days trying to learn the basic of that language. 
Basically I want to go through all my files (for simplicity they are in the same folder), extract the few lines that I need and copy them in one line in an output file.

So far I managed to:

Extract all lines from every files in one output file

```
FOR %%f IN (*.whl) DO FOR /F "delims=|" %%l in (%%f) DO echo %%l >> output.txt
```

Extract the lines (5 and 10) I want from one file

```
(FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO SET /P line1=) < file.txt
(FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO SET /P line2=) < file.txt
>> output.txt ECHO %line1% %line2%
```

Now I'm trying to combine those two previous code:

That code give me the correct output for the first file but doesn't loop through all files. If I add a `goto nxt_file` at the end of the block `:extract_lines` it just doing the first file over again.

```
:nxt_file
FOR %%f IN (*.whl) DO (
    set outfile=%%f
    goto extract_lines)

:extract_lines
(FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO SET /P line1=) < %file%
(FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO SET /P line2=) < %file%
>> output.txt ECHO %line1% %line2%
```

That code loop but fail to copy the lines I want in the output.

```
FOR %%f IN (*.whl) DO (
    (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO SET /P line1=) < %%f
    (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO SET /P line2=) < %%f

    ECHO %line1% %line2%  >>  output.txt 
)
```

But if I change it adding `set file=%%f` and replace `< %%f` by `< %file%` it doesn't run.

By the way I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851018/extracting-specific-lines-of-data-from-multiple-text-files-to-convert-to-a-sing), which work well but I wonder if I can sort it out with the method I used so far.

Thank for your help!

EDIT: As you can see this is my first post and also my first steps in that language. I welcome any advice to make this question and maybe future question more detailed as I may not perceive every information that are relevant to an advanced user.

Thanks to @Magoo my question is solved, but I would be interested by any advice to make this code better (I guess there is a more efficient way to select only the line I need instead of using `FOR /L` and going through every line until the right one).

Also if any person have explanation about the different problems I described (e.g. `< %%f` instead of `< %file%`) would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an XY problem to me (IOW - attempting to fix a method, not a problem)

(this is untested, as it has to be, given the lack of detail)

```
FOR %%f IN (*.whl) DO (
 (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO SET /P line1=) < %%f
 (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO SET /P line2=) < %%f
 >> output.txt CALL ECHO %%line1%% %%line2%%
)
```

should find each `*.whl` file, assigning the name to `%%f`, then read the first 5 lines from that file to `line1` and the first 10 to `line2`, leaving the fifth an tenth lines in those two variables, then accumulate the outputs into `output.txt`

**IF** I am interpreting your method correctly...

Comment: Indeed it solve my problem! Thanks! But could you explain me why do you need to write `CALL ECHO` it's the first time I see it written like that. Also why are `line1` and `line2` with two set of `%%`? I though it was enough to write `%line1%` for a variable. You're right, the `FOR /L` doesn't seem to be the best way to do it. Would there be a way to go directly on the line I want? I tried to explain my problem with the most detail possible. What information should I have add to be more specific?

Comment: The `call echo %%var%%` uses a parsing trick. Since `%%` parses to `%` (so you can echo a `%` symbol), the line is interpreted as `echo %var%` but executed with a copy of the current environment, hence displaying the current value of the variable. Without the `call`, `%var%` (literally) would be displayed, and `echo %var%` would show the vakue of `var` as it was when the block (parenthesised series of commands) was first entered. There are other ways to do this - what I've shown is the easiest. Search SO for `delayedexpansion` for hundreds of articles on this FAQ.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the `for /L` method you've used to select lines 5 and 10. The lucky thing is that they are fixed line numbers - something like "the fifth line after the third occurrence of `xyzzpl` in the file" would be far harder to implement.

Comment: Detailed explanation is good - but presenting the question in the form "what I am trying to do" "code I'm using" "desired result" "actual result" and some relevant data - like filename-structure or sample data is of great assistance. If you get into the details before you mention the problem to be solved, people are likely to abandon the question. It's important to recognise that presenting the problem to be solved must take priority over fixing the solution chosen as you may have made a wrong choice of approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do it all in a single `For` loop using `FindStr`.

```bat
@Echo Off
>outfile.txt (For /F "Tokens=2* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" *.whl'
) Do If "%%A"=="5" (Set "_=%%B") Else If "%%A"=="10" (Call Echo=%%_%% %%B))
```