# Parsing a delimited config file using FOR on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a java properties file to parse, it contains key value pairs of the form key=value, one on each line.
After digging around on the site, I've found [this site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php) that explains the FOR syntax, and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206114/dos-batch-files-how-to-read-a-file).

I constructed the following line to get the value of the backupdir.windows property in config.properties:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %i in ('findstr backupdir.windows= config.properties') do  @echo %i
```

The above works if you type it at the command prompt, but if I save it as a file 'test.cmd' and then execute that, I get  '**i was unexpected at this time.**'
Same thing happens if I change the extension to .bat (in case doing so would make it use
earlier MSDOS syntax).

What's going wrong here? I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Simply double the percent signs from `%i` to `%%i` inside of a batch file

Comment: @jeb If you write that in as an answer instead of a comment, then Rex could give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to do it like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /b /i "backupdir.windows" config.properties') do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

it needs to be %%i in a batch file. And just %i on the command line.