# Find and replace a string in multiple files using Batch script

Tags: batch-file, replace, find

I have more 3000 files in a folder. I want to find and replace text with another one. How can I do that?
I'm a newbie in batch script. I can replace it in 1 file but I don't know how to replace in multiple files.

```
FOR /F %%L IN (lala.txt) DO (
    SET "line=%%L"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set "x=!line:E:\Test=E:\Test\Temp!"
    echo f | xcopy /E !line! !x! 
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

How can I edit my code to replace the string in all files?
Waiting for your help. Thanks

Comment: use the 1 file code in a for loop for all files

Comment: Excuse me, Your code above does _not_ replace any string in one file! The contents of lala.txt file remains unchanged...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the [Find And Replace Text command line utility](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) and then you can simply enter

```
fart *.txt E:\Test E:\Test\Temp
```

Comment: Great utility. Works as advertised. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a second loop for the files.

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    FOR /F %%L IN (%%f) DO (
      SET "line=%%L"
      SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
      set "x=!line:E:\Test=E:\Test\Temp!" 
      echo f | xcopy /E !line! !x! 
      ENDLOCAL
  )
)
```

This code shows only how to build the loop for process all text files.
The inner code uses the code of the OP, which will not replace anything, but this wasn't the question.

Comment: i'm curious why you enable delayed expansion inside the loop, isn't more eficient to do it just once outside the loop?

Comment: and, what is in the echo|xcopy combination that replaces the original file?

Comment: I just copy the original block from the OP :-) But the EnableDelayedExpansion should be inside the loop for the [safe toggling technic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4531090/463115)