# Find and replace string in several xml files

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, batch-rename

I need to replace a string "AVL_P" with "AVL_PRESSURE" in several XML files. Would someone be able to help me do this using a .bat file?

The xml files are in a directory called C:\ECU\ECU1, ECU2 and ECU3 folders.

Thanks
John.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace a string in multiple files using Batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645848/find-and-replace-a-string-in-multiple-files-using-batch-script)

Comment: See also [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/) This question offers more than 20 possible solutions.