# Reading a text file line by line and storing it in an array using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to read a text file and store each line in an array. When I used the code below, `"echo %i%"` is printing `0` every time and only `array[0]` value is getting assigned. But in `"set n=%i%"`,`n` value is assigned as the last incremented I value.Also `"@echo !array[%%i]!"` is printing like `!array[0]!` instead of printing the value. Is there any syntax error in the code?

```
set /A i=0

for /F %%a in (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\url.txt) do (

set /A i+=1

echo %i%

set array[%i%]=%%a

)

set n=%i%

for /L %%i in (0,1,%n%) do @echo !array[%%i]!
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch files: How to read a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206114/batch-files-how-to-read-a-file)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a method that is useful at times and very similar to your code:

```
@echo off
set "file=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\url.txt"
set /A i=0

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
set /A i+=1
call echo %%i%%
call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
call set n=%%i%%
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do call echo %%array[%%i]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\url.txt) do (
    set /A count+=1
    set "array[!count!]=%%a"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do echo !array[%%i]!
```

Inside a code block you need `delayed expansion` and `!variables!`.

Answer (score 0):

Read `set /?` description about environment run-time linking. When you are using `%i%` inside `for` - it is pre-expanded **before** `for` execution. You need to use `!i!` instead.

Comment: Thanks Maximus,I replaced %i% with !i!. Now "echo !i!" is printing !i! and "array[!i!]=%%a" is assigning the values as array[!i!]. The value if i is not applied while using "!".

Comment: I think you have not read `set /?`. Read it carefully about cmd and /v switch.

Comment: @NagaLakshmi - Within a batch file, you can use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('findstr /n /r "$" url.txt') DO SET max=%%i&SET array[%%i]=%%j
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,%max%) DO CALL ECHO(%%array[%%i]%%
GOTO :EOF
```

provided no line begins ":"