# Copy files from a file list to a folder list in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two text files...`files.txt` containing a list of filenames and `dirs.txt` containing the list of directories the files need to be copied to.
This is how the files need to be copied:

```
File 1 ------------------------> Folder 1  
File 2 ------------------------> Folder 2  
File 3 ------------------------> Folder 3
```

How do I implement this using batch? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please specify the reason for downvote...do I need to provide additional information?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, (it is similar to some other questions) but there is nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: Does exactly one file go into each folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to figure it out...thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869970/2966174) answer from @foxidrive.  Here is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A i=0
for /F "usebackq delims==" %%a in (files.txt) do (
set /A i+=1
call set array1[%%i%%]=%%a
call set n=%%i%%
)
set /A i=0
for /F "usebackq delims==" %%a in (dirs.txt) do (
set /A i+=1
call set array2[%%i%%]=%%a
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do call copy "%%array1[%%i]%%" "%%array2[%%i]%%"
```

It's definitely not the best solution...but it works!
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (files.txt) do (
set /p dir=
echo copy "%%~a" "!dir!"
)<dirs.txt
pause
```

The above works - Mona can revise or remove the following:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
3<dirs.txt(
for /f "delims=" %%a in (files.txt) do (
set /p dir=<&3
copy "%%~a" "!dir!"
)
)
```

And that should do what you want. Note if dirs.txt has less lines then files.txt, this will fail.

Mona.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work..  
This is what I get:  

`E:\>cmd.bat  

E:\>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
The syntax of the command is incorrect.  

E:\>3<dirs.txt(  

E:\>
`

Comment: See the edit above - it only echos the command to the screen.

Comment: Hi @foxidrive...I tried your edit. However it is copying all the files to `Folder 1` which is the **1st** item in `dirs.txt`.