# Read .txt line by line into batch variables

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a batch script which sends pings to some PCs. The available PCs are written into a text file, so each PC stands in its own line. Another batch script copies some files to the PCs (at the moment it tries to copy to all PCs).

Now I want to modify the script(s) so the batch reads out the text file and only copies to the available PCs … but how?
It should read the written lines of the text file line by line and check for EOF.

Comment: You can ping the machines and immediately copy the required files to online PCs.  It's not clear why you are testing for machines and apparently copying files some time later when the machines may no longer be online.

Comment: Indeed you are right and i added it as the best solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want, but according to your question *"Read .txt line by line and put it into variables"*, this might be useful for you.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set count=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (textfile.txt) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set var[!count!]=%%x
)
echo %var[4]%
pause >nul
```

`echo %var[4]%` will print out the 4th line in textfile.txt (or any text file).