# PuTTY Plink save files name to text file, and PSFTP only those

Tags: sftp, putty, plink

I am trying to take the files that I get with PuTTY's Plink command but save the file names to a text file so that I can only pull those files with PSFTP afterwards. Or can this be done without a temp text file?

The files I get are modified in the last 15 min, and I only want to get those files. I am new to PuTTY and FTP in general. I searched everywhere but cannot find anything that helps.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate the PSFTP script file dynamically by reading the Plink output file line by line and producing a `put` command for each line.

See [Batch files: How to read a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206114/850848)

---

Or use an SFTP client that can directly download only files created in the last 15 minutes.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation):

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""fingerprint""" ^
    "get /path/*>15N c:\path\" ^
    "exit"
```

Read about [file masks with a time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*