# Batch File - Copy file to user profile using text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am looking for a quick way to copy data from one location to multiple user profile locations on the server share.  The only change in the destination path is the username.

I want to target specific users, and those user ID are in a text file.

Can I loop though this list replacing the username in the path and make the copy?

I can do this the long way either manual copy, or create hundreds of lines, and changing the username for each copy using the below command

```
XCOPY C:\Shortcuts\* \\Server\Share\%USERNAME%\Profile\Favorites\Shortcuts /s /I
```

Many thanks

Comment: I wouldn't copy the shortcut and create it instead. See here: http://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd

Comment: And at least part of your question seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206114/batch-files-how-to-read-a-file

Comment: Cheers horse.  I'll review those other threads.  I did review other threads before posting up but I will review the threads you have posted and see if I can put together a solution.  Cheers the -1!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds easy. Let's assume you want to copy `X:\someDir` to `Y:\%USERNAME%\someDir` using any user name listed in a text file (`user_list.txt` or something) as %USERNAME%.

```
FOR /F %%U IN (user_list.txt) DO (
    XCOPY X:\someDir Y:\%%U\someDir /E /Y /I
)
```

This should work as long as your user names don't contain special characters.

Comment: Thank you MichaelS. I gave this a go but I get an error %UU not expected at this time.   I'll check out the other threads that the horse put up before coming back

Comment: @user3364233 `%%u` will only work when used in a batch, in case you try this directly on the command line you will have to write `%u`

Comment: Thank you Marged.  My batch file did not like the %uu however using just %u from the command line worked fine and I am happy with this to get the job done    FOR /F %U IN (C:\LOOPTEST\USERLIST.TXT) DO xcopy c:\looptest\test\* c:\looptest\%U\favorites /s /I

Comment: @user3364233 It's not %UU, it's %%U! Inside a bat you should use %%U and %U from the command line.

Comment: %UU was a typo above. Just checked and what i use direct from a command line does not work in batch file. No bother lad, your solution worked for me and I achieved what i set out to do