# How to escape / pass the % character to the Sub

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping, findstr

I have this batch file, where I am trying to extract a substring but in the end result the `%` character is being removed. Eg `some%value` becomes `somevalue`. I have escaped the `&amp;` character but nothing works for the percent character.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /I "<start>.*</end>" "AllApiLogs.log"') Do (
    Call :Sub "%%A"
)
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "Line=%~1"
Set "Line=%Line:&amp;=^&%"
Set "Up2Sub=%Line:*<start>=%"
Set "SubStr=%Up2Sub:</end>="&:"%"
Echo '%SubStr%', >> ApiRegExExtract.log
Exit /B
```

How do I work around this?
Is there a way to escape all characters that need escaping in batch files? I am new to these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you lose the percent sign by using `Call :Sub "%%A"`.

Just change that to:

```
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /I "<start>.*</end>" "AllApiLogs.log"') Do (
    set "line=%%A"
    Call :Sub
)
GoTo :EOF

:Sub

Set "Line=%Line:&amp;=^&%"
...
```

It's an effect of the `CALL` command, it parses the arguments two times

Comment: That worked. Thank you. 

Are there any other characters I need to take care off?

Comment: Bullet proof replacing with batch is a bit tricky. Even [reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531090/463115) line by line is tricky enough

Answer (score 1):

You can not escape a % with a caret.
You can escape a % by doubling it, so for % use a % to escape this character.